# Why can't I access static content with Windows Authentication in IIS

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, windows-authentication, application-pool

I am trying to follow best security practices in IIS for my ASP.NET website, so I have the following set-up:

1. Dedicated Integrated AppPool (v4.0) that authenticates with AppPoolIdentity
2. Website with only **Windows Authentication** enabled (Anonymous Authentication is disabled), *Extended Protection* is set to **Required**
3. AppPoolIdentity and Local Administrators group have read-only access to website folder

I am able to access my website in the browser, Windows automatically submits current credentials and my Controller serves the View. Now, the problem is that any static content that is not served by the Controller, such as .js, .css and images is not loading.

What I've observed:

- If I access static content directly (e.g. website.com/js/script.js), Chrome asks for credentials
- If correct credentials are provided, it rejects and asks again and again
- If the popup is cancelled, **401.3 - Unauthorized** error is seen
- I'm not sure if it is involved here, but *Static Content* feature is installed
- I have used Sysinternals Process Monitor to see what is happening under the hood and I noticed that when in the browser I request for a View, the view is accessed by AppPoolIdentity, however when I request for static content the application tries to access it with my current Windows Identity, which obviously doesn't have access to the physical folder

It is the same problem as described in https://forums.iis.net/t/1172827.aspx?Windows+Authentication+cant+load+images, with the exception that Authenticated Users, System and Web Servers groups don't really need the NTFS access to the folder. In that forum the solution has never been found.

---

The question is: why it is happening and how can I change my configuration so I still comply with the best practices (Anonymous Authentication is not an option, neither is an option to grant all users the access to the actual folder with static content on the server), but in the same time painlessly serve static content to the users.

My understanding is that Windows Authentication is supposed to authenticate the user in the App and let the app know that it is me, but it is not supposed to be involved into ACL-level manipulations.

**UPDATE**: I have found out that .js and .css files can be served using ASP.NET MVC Bundling, in this case as I understand they are served together with the View so no additional HTTP Requests are required. However, I still have no clue what can I do about images.

Comment: I tried the  same thing on my side and static content should be accessed via app pool. Have you tried to set system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/useAppPoolCredentials=true.

Comment: @JokiesDing it is set to `false`, however, changing it to `true` and reloading the website didn't help.

Comment: In 2023, still the same problem and still no solution anywhere. We're running into this on IIS 10